# Windowing Functions in Piglatin ( rank over() etc)

Tags: apache-pig

Is it possible to implement Windowing functions in piglatin? I am currently on a verison of Hive that does not support rank over() clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you out:  rank was implemented in Pig v. .11 [(version 12 rank document](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#rank)) and  [over() was implemented as a piggybank object](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Over.html).

Example Usage:

```
To do a cumulative sum:

 A = load 'T';
 B = group A by si
 C = foreach B {
     C1 = order A by d;
     generate flatten(Stitch(C1, Over(C1.f, 'sum(float)')));
 }
 D = foreach C generate s, $9;


This is equivalent to the SQL statement

select s, sum(f) over (partition by si order by d) from T;
```

```
To find the record 3 ahead of the current record, using a window between the current row and 3 records ahead and a default value of 0.

 A = load 'T';
 B = group A by si;
 C = foreach B {
     C1 = order A by i;
     generate flatten(Stitch(C1, Over(C1.i, 'lead', 0, 3, 3, 0)));
 }
 D = foreach C generate s, $9;


This is equivalent to the SQL statement

select s, lead(i, 3, 0) over (partition by si order by i rows between current row and 3 following) over T;
```

Comment: Glad to help! If an answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to that answer.  That marks it as 'answered' in the questions list, which helps people focus on the questions that still need answers.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information.

Comment: Marked! Quick asside -- Is it possible to stitch together multiple calls to Over? In the first pig example, is it possible to stitch together a Over() call to sum  AND an over call to count? I can see the possibility of doing this with a join (run the sum code, then join a dataset with a running count) however, with a dataset of billions of rows it seems impractical.

Comment: I don't think it's possible ... from the docs, it looks like it wants just one aggregate function to perform.

Comment: The Stitch UDF accepts any number of bags, so you can do `Stitch(C1, Over(C1.f, 'sum(float)')), Over(C1, 'count')))`

Comment: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Over.html